# Redirect automatically to Identity Server login page without clicking on login button - Angular 8

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular8, identityserver4

I am trying to redirect automatically from my angular client by navigating this path `http://localhost:4200/login` to the template login form of the Identity server, without clicking on a button.

Now I am succeeding to navigate the login page in the Identity server by clicking a `login()` button that implementing this function `this.oidcSecurityService.authorize()` from `angular-auth-oidc-client` package.

So how I can run this function `this.oidcSecurityService.authorize()` automatically once navigating to `http://localhost:4200/login` without clicking the `login()` button ?

This is my `login.component.html` :

```
<h1>Login With Identity Server</h1>

<div class="card-container">
<mat-card class="card"> 
   <button *ngIf="!isAuthorized" mat-button type="submit" (click)="userlogin()"><mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title></button>
   <button *ngIf="isAuthorized" mat-button type="submit" (click)="userlogout()"><mat-card-title>Logout</mat-card-title></button>
</mat-card>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my `login.component.ts` :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  isAuthorizedSubscription: Subscription;
  isAuthorized: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.initAuth();
    this.isAuthorizedSubscription = this.authService.getIsAuthorized().subscribe(
      (isAuthorized: boolean) => {
        this.isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
      });
  }

  public userlogin() {
      this.authService.login();
  }

  public userlogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}
```

This is my `auth-guard.service` :

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router,  private authService: AuthService) { }
  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.authService.getIsAuthorized().pipe(map((isAuthorized: boolean) => {
        if (isAuthorized) {
            return true;
        }
        // Stores the attempted URL for redirecting.
        this.authService.setRedirectUrl(state.url);

        // Not signed in so redirects to unauthorized page.
        this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
        return false;
    }));
  }
}
```

And this is my routes :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '', // this path should return the template login page of the Identity Server
      redirectTo: '/login',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
     path: 'home',
     component: HomeComponent,
     canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
    },
```

*Note: This `path: ''` should return the template login page of the Identity Server once redirecting to `/login`.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to solve it !
Just by changing the `login.component.ts` like that :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.initAuth();
    this.authService.login();
  }
```

Now it is redirecting automatically to the login page of the Identity server.

Thank you ...

Comment: Hi I am having thesame question but I am using OidcSecurityService in the app.component.ts. How can I be redirected to the ID server straight away without using these buttons?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can explicitly redirect to the page.

```js
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.initAuth();
    this.isAuthorizedSubscription = this.authService.getIsAuthorized().subscribe(
      (isAuthorized: boolean) => {
        this.isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
        if (!isAuhorized) {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      });
  }
```

Or explicitly call the AuthService login() metod:

```js
  constructor(private authService: AuthService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.initAuth();
    this.isAuthorizedSubscription = this.authService.getIsAuthorized().subscribe(
      (isAuthorized: boolean) => {
        this.isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
        if (!isAuthorized) {
          this.authService.login();
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried your solutions, but it didn't redirect to any path, still in the same login component.

Comment: Can you put a console.log inside the subscription to see if it is actually being called?

Comment: I added, it isn't called :(